# Safari does not render the height of div when using CSS3 columns and Boostrap

Tags: css, safari, css-multicolumn-layout

I have an issue with Safari 10.0.3 while working with CSS3 columns and Bootstrap.

It does not render the height of the div correctly (actually displays with no height)

Turning off the css for columns and content displays as normal in one column with the correct height.

Has anyone come across this issue before and have a solution/work around to correctly render the height of the parent div?

EDIT
Please see this full example on CodePen to replicate issue – the Code I have used is below.
https://codepen.io/FiascoDesign/pen/JNrZvX

```
<style>
.parent {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.left-column,.right-column {
  float:left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .parent .right-column {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 50px;
    -moz-column-gap: 50px;
    column-gap: 50px;
  }
}
</style>
<div class="col-xs-12 parent">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 left-column"><h3>Section title</h3></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 right-column">
    <p><b>title of thing</b><br />
    description of thing that runs on over a few lines</p>
    <p><b>title of thing</b><br />
    description of thing that runs on over a few lines</p>
    <p><b>title of thing</b><br />
    description of thing that runs on over a few lines</p>
    <p><b>title of thing</b><br />
    description of thing that runs on over a few lines</p><p><b>title of thing</b><br />
    description of thing that runs on over a few lines</p>
    <p><b>title of thing</b><br />
    description of thing that runs on over a few lines</p>
    <p><b>title of thing</b><br />
    description of thing that runs on over a few lines</p>
    <p><b>title of thing</b><br />
    description of thing that runs on over a few lines</p>
    <p><b>title of thing</b><br />
    description of thing that runs on over a few lines</p>
    <p><b>title of thing</b><br />
    description of thing that runs on over a few lines</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pete please see my edited question with  more in depth code. I hope this is a better way to format a question to hopefully get an answer. Thanks.

Comment: You should have a better chance now, unfortunately I don't have safari so cannot help

Comment: Don't know what exactly you want. But when I use Safari 10.1 on MacOS 10.12 to visit your CodePen link, it gives the same result as Chrome.

Comment: try using "!important" and check, might help you

Comment: Sadly trying out "!important" didn't seem to work for me. And @shaochuancs I'm on the same MacOS but still see this issue in Safari. 

Basically the right hand Bootstrap column does not have any height from 768px and up after my breakpoint. (Seems to show 1px) rather than showing all the items within the Bootstrap column. 

There seems to be a known issue that sounds similar (and renders the same issue I am having) on http://caniuse.com/#search=column
Last issue within known issues tab.